# How to add a custom request header to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, header, xmlhttprequest

I want to add a custom header to an iframe component. There are different options I saw, where all of them makes an xhr request first with the desired headers and pass that object to src attribute of the iframe. This will result in 2 API calls (one while making initial call and next while loading the URL with iframe). Is there a way to avoid it. I need to restrict only to a single call.